# Run action only on parent sknode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

As title says. How to run SKAction only on parent only (children not affected by it)?

I have some SKSpriteNodes with children, but I would like to manually control which actions are run on each children and that actions are not inherited from parent

Comment: wouldn't make sense,  you are saying that you want to  spin the planet, but keep all the people stationary.  Instead you need to make another child that would be your so called parent, and apply 0 actions to the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpriteKit does not work this way. If your children should not be affected by the parent's movement, perhaps you should reconsider making them children.

However, there is a fun workaround: run an action on the children that counteracts the parent's movement. For example, if you run an action on the parent that moves to the left, run an action on all the children that moves them to the right simultaneously.

Comment: Running counter actions is a terrible idea,  that is more work on the processor that is not needed

Comment: Not a terrible idea if that's the behavior you're looking for--for example, a node that almost always moved its children along except in this one special case. If you're ALWAYS going to be countering, though, then you should not have children in the first place, as I said.

Comment: Having a counter action run on a single child it not a terrible idea,  but if you have more than one (hence children), then it becomes a terrible idea and should instead be grouped

Comment: I have solved this problem with changing structure, but problem I have now is how to "copy" certain action from one node to another.
Doing this doesn't work:
onesprite.runAction(othersprite.actionForKey("someaction")!)